# Number of different values / distinct in a column per ID in a sorted dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sorted dataframe with an ID, and a value column, which looks like:

```
ID   value 
A    10
A    10
A    10
B    15
B    15
C    10
C    10
...
```

How can i create a new dataframe, that it counts the "new" distinct values in terms of the number of different IDS, so that it basically goes over my dataframe and looks like:

```
Number of ID  Number of distinct values
1             1
2             2
3             2
```

In that case above we have 3 different IDs, but ID A and C have the same value.

So the first row in the new dataframe:
Numer of ID = 1, because we have 1 different ID so far
Number of distinct values= 1 , because we have one distinct value so far

Second row:
Number of ID=2, because we are going to row 4 in the old dataframe( we only are interessted in new IDS)
Number of disntinct values=2, because the value changed to 15 and didn't occur so far

Comment: `Number of distinct values` - why not all values `1` ?

Comment: Why the first row is 1 1

Comment: see my edits, i tried to give more content

Comment: I am only interested in the development of the values, so that is why i want to count only "new" values

Comment: I hope I understand, but not 100% sure, if not is possible add some new rows for data sample?

Comment: the solution is working, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need processing new DataFrame by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `factorize` and `cumsum`:

Replace duplicated values to `NaN`, forward filling them and then call `pd.factorize`:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['ID','value']).copy()
df1['Number of ID'] = range(1, len(df1)+1)
df1['Number of distinct values'] = pd.factorize(df1['value'].mask(df1['value'].duplicated()).ffill())[0] + 1
print (df1)
  ID  value  Number of ID  Number of distinct values
0  A     10             1                          1
3  B     15             2                          2
5  C     10             3                          2
```

I change data for better testing:

```
print (df)
  ID  value
0  A     10
1  A     10
2  A     10
3  B     15
4  B     15
5  C     10
6  C     15

df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['ID','value']).copy()
df1['Number of ID'] = range(1, len(df1)+1)
df1['Number of distinct values'] = pd.factorize(df1['value'].mask(df1['value'].duplicated()).ffill())[0] + 1
print (df1)
  ID  value  Number of ID  Number of distinct values
0  A     10             1                          1
3  B     15             2                          2
5  C     10             3                          2
6  C     15             4                          2
```

Working wrong if multiple values `value` per `ID`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number of ID': range(1, len(df1)+1),
                   'Number of distinct values': np.cumsum(pd.factorize(df1['value'])[0])+1})
print (df)
   Number of ID  Number of distinct values
0             1                          1
1             2                          2
2             3                          2
3             4                          3
```